# WeChat to GBP or USD?

Tags: currency

I have several thousand CNY in WeChat. I'd like to convert it to either GBP or USD. Do any expats have experience with this or know of any methods?

Comment: I feel that this is off topic, as it is not something that affects only expatriates. This is a basic banking issue that could affect anyone using WeChat.

Comment: I won't contest your point, but if you can suggest an appropriate medium to ask this question that would be wonderful.